# Kentico 9 media library files are 0KB after upload

Tags: kentico

I think this is a server setting issue, but when image are uploaded, the file length ends up being 0kb. I don't get any errors in the event log. I can see the file written to the server, it just has no data. I don't know where to look for a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step i would do is make sure the IIS Application pool has full security control over your CMS folder.  If you don't have this set, it may not allow it to write files/modify.  You can do this by right clicking on your CMS folder and going to Properties, Security, add user, and search for the user "IIS APPPOOL\TheAppPoolName" on the local machine.

If you're hosted, they may have tools in their file editor to do the same.

Comment: Oddly enough, iis_iuser as full control. While a file is written, it's empty. That's what i can't figure out. I don't think it's a permission error.

Comment: That was the issue. the App Pool account could create the file, but not fill it.